# Get rid of a dimension by concatenating into another dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D **Numpy** array:

```
a = np.array([[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]])
```

Now, I'd like to get rid of dimension 0, by concatenating the elements along current dimension 1 (= new dimension 0). So I'd end up with the following array:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

(I might also want to do this along another dimension.)

Basically, it's no big deal to do it with `reshape`, but it requires some manual size calculation. **Is there a convenience function to do it directly?**

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding you, but `array(chain(*l))` works for the example you gave

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: The question is about Numpy ndarrays. I edited the question to make it a bit more obvious ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be with [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) as it stacks vertically (row wise) -

```
np.vstack(a)
```

Even [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) works too as by default it concatenates along the first axis -

```
np.concatenate(a)
```

Stating the reshaping based one too for completeness -

```
a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])
```

Comment: The reshape will be a view; the concatenate a copy.